# Sign up new customers from an outer form in Prestashop

Tags: e-commerce, prestashop

I need to allow a quick registration in a **Prestashop** web to our visitors in a trade fair, and I've made a registration form outside the Prestashop framework with just a few fields (1st name, surname, email, postal code/zip, newsletter checkbox and conditions/privacy agreement). It must be a clean screen with just the logo and the form. When the visitors send it, a process must store their data.

What I'm not sure of is which table fields should the process fill in in order to have them enabled as new users when they sign in.

I suppose it's necessary to fill in the "not null" fields without defaults in **"ps_customer"**, and in **"ps_address"**. Is any additional table necessary? How's the password generation algorithm? The process will create it and send it to the new user.

Maybe someone of you needed to do this previously, or maybe you simply know the intrincacies of Prestashop's registration process. I haven't had enough time to delve into it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the prestashop web api:

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service

The docs actually include an example of this exact scenario